# WGCNA for multiple phenotype and gene expression

Tags: r

I am using `WGCNA` package for network analysis with following steps:

1. Data input
2. Generate Modules
3. Get gene id
4. Phenotype x module correlation

I want to use the package to include the phenotype data together with the gene expression matrix to find which genes group with the phenotypes. Then, I want to get the module of interest and do a network map and check which genes relate to the phenotypes.

I generated modules like:

```
library(WGCNA)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
enableWGCNAThreads()
lnames = load(file = "dataInput.RData");

# Choose a set of soft-thresholding powers
powers = c(c(1:10), seq(from = 12, to=40, by=2))
# Call the network topology analysis function
sft = pickSoftThreshold(datExpr, powerVector = powers, verbose = 5)
# Plot the results:
sizeGrWindow(9, 5)
par(mfrow = c(1,2));
cex1 = 0.9;
# Scale-free topology fit index as a function of the soft-thresholding power
plot(sft$fitIndices[,1], -sign(sft$fitIndices[,3])*sft$fitIndices[,2],
     xlab="Soft Threshold (power)",ylab="Scale Free Topology Model Fit,signed R^2",type="n",
     main = paste("Scale independence"));
text(sft$fitIndices[,1], -sign(sft$fitIndices[,3])*sft$fitIndices[,2],
     labels=powers,cex=cex1,col="red");
# this line corresponds to using an R^2 cut-off of h
abline(h=0.90,col="red")
# Mean connectivity as a function of the soft-thresholding power
plot(sft$fitIndices[,1], sft$fitIndices[,5],
     xlab="Soft Threshold (power)",ylab="Mean Connectivity", type="n",
     main = paste("Mean connectivity"))
text(sft$fitIndices[,1], sft$fitIndices[,5], labels=powers, cex=cex1,col="red")


##Constructing the gene network and identifying modules is now a simple function call:
net_unsigned = blockwiseModules(datExpr, power = 6,
                                  TOMType = "unsigned", minModuleSize = 30, maxBlockSize = 300,
                                  reassignThreshold = 0, mergeCutHeight = 0.25,
                                  numericLabels = TRUE, pamRespectsDendro = FALSE,
                                  saveTOMs = TRUE,
                                  saveTOMFileBase = "PopulusTOM_signed",
                                  verbose = 5)
##maxBlockSize = The total number of genes you have in your gene expression matrix that passed the filter from Data_Input scrip
##Plotting graph
pdf("Dendogram_Modules_signed.pdf", width = 30, height = 30);
##Convert labels to colors for plotting
mergedColors = labels2colors(net_unsigned$colors)
##Plot the dendrogram and the module colors underneath
plotDendroAndColors(net_unsigned$dendrograms[[1]], mergedColors[net_unsigned$blockGenes[[1]]],
                    "Module colors",
                    dendroLabels = FALSE, hang = 0.03,
                    addGuide = TRUE, guideHang = 0.05)
dev.off()
##Save
moduleLabels = net_unsigned$colors
moduleColors = labels2colors(net_unsigned$colors)
MEs = net_unsigned$MEs;
geneTree = net_unsigned$dendrograms[[1]];
save(MEs, moduleLabels, moduleColors, geneTree,
     file = "unsigned-networkConstruction-auto.RData")
```

This generates modules and then I correlated a module with one phenotype. How can I include the phenotypic data with gene expression? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the WGCNA package has the functionality for multi-omic analysis. Try using [smccNet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SmCCNet/index.html). Here is the link to the [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30957844/)

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking how to recover the gene IDs represented by your module of interest? Or are you asking what kind of test you may conduct to test the association between phenotype (discrete I suppose) and gene expression (continuous I suppose)?

Comment: Thank you @YuanYin! I want to know how can I test the association between multiple phenotypes and gene expression.

Comment: If your phenotype is discrete and the cardinality is 2 (say, male vs. female), you can do a t-test. If there are more than 2 (say, blood types), you can do ANOVA. If your phenotype is continuous, maybe you can do some simple correlation for linear association? Note that if you have a lot of genes to test, you need to do multiple test correction (such as Benjamini-Hochberg method). All these methods are well explained online so you may want to look them up.